# How can I make the intersection of two SKSpriteNodes transparent

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, transparent, fragment-shader, skspritenode

I added a background SKSpriteNode as a child to my SKScene.  This node itself has some children nodes.  Each child has some colored pixels as well as totally transparent pixels. The children nodes are moving across the screen and sometimes intersect each other.

I'd like to make the intersecting colored areas of the children fully transparent as they move so that the background sprite shows through. For the non-intersecting areas of each child, the node should appear as normal. I tried playing around with the blendmode but couldn't get the desired effect. Any ideas how to do this?  Or, is there a way to do this outside of SpriteKit?

Thanks

Comment: Digging around, it looks like it might be possible by assigning an SKShader to my child node and passing in the background texture to the shader as a uniform.  To simulate the transparent effect, I would find the corresponding pixel in the background texture.  However, it seems like I would need to know the position of the child node relative to the background node to do this.  This could be done by changing a uniform every frame but I'm sure that will lead to poor performance.   Will need to try this later, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are commands to achieve what you want. You can change the the entire texture/image of a sprite, you can change part of a sprite's texture/image appearance by using a filter but you cannot specifically modify part of a sprite's texture/image. To be more specific, a sprite's alpha property applies to the entire sprite and not just part of it.